# How Can I Make These Links Rotate in PHP?

Tags: php

Below is the code I'm using.

I would like to be able to rotate a random link to the user.

Instead of just link1.com , I would like it to rotate between link1.com / link2.com / link3.com

How can I modify this code to do that?

Thank you in advance!!!

```
<?php

    require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
    $geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
    $geoplugin->locate();


   $geo_region = $geoplugin->region;  

    switch($geo_region) {
        case 'CA':
             header('Location: http://www.link1.com');
             exit; 



        default: // exceptions
               header('Location: http://www.everyoneelsegoeshere.com');
               exit;

         }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one:

```
require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
$geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
$geoplugin->locate();
$geo_region = $geoplugin->region;

$links = array('link1.com','link2.com','link3.com');

switch($geo_region) {
    case 'CA':
         header('Location: http://'.$links[array_rand($links)]);
         exit; 
    default: // exceptions
        header('Location: http://www.everyoneelsegoeshere.com');
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: I tried to vote for best answer, but my reputation is not high enough yet. When it is, I will come back and vote. Thanks again.